# how to read data sent from post Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=

Tags: php

can you guy's help me with this plz

i have data sent from post Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=

-poster.php is sending post

-reciver.php is the file im posting to

```
--------------------------42281d81075fd0d5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="one"

this is one
--------------------------42281d81075fd0d5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="two"

this is two
--------------------------42281d81075fd0d5--
```

so what i want to know is how i can get those values
i dont think $_POST[''];

i can't figur it out

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can access the values by `$_POST['one']` and `$_POST['two']` in case of **normal form data**.

If you want to read a **file** that you uploaded you can access this by using `$_FILES['name_of_file_input_field']`.

Answer (score 0):

when you using some php framework and `jQuery` then you receiving your data like that. You might jQuery **ajax setting** with `contentType` set to false. Then you can get the data like you want.